# Removing Root Node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, root-node

I'm currently unable to delete the root node of my binary search tree in these situations

1. the root node doesn't have a left attribute or doesn't have a right attribute
2. the root has neither attribute (leaf)

```
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import Any, Optional


class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value: Any, left: BST, right: BST):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"TreeNode({self.value}, {self.left}, {self.right})"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value and \
            self.right == other.right and self.left == other.left


BST = Optional[TreeNode]


def is_empty(tree: BST) -> bool:
    """Return True if the tree is empty, False otherwise."""
    return tree is None  # check if BST input is none (empty)


def search(tree: BST, value: Any) -> bool:
    """Return True if value is in tree, False otherwise."""
    if tree is None:
        return False
    else:
        return (
            tree.value == value
            or search(tree.left, value)
            or search(tree.right, value)
        )


def insert(tree: BST, value: Any) -> BST:
    """Insert the value into the tree in the proper location."""
    if tree is None:
        return TreeNode(value, None, None)
    elif tree.value is None:
        tree.value = value
    elif value > tree.value:
        if tree.right is None:
            tree.right = TreeNode(value, None, None)
        return insert(tree.right, value)
    elif value < tree.value:
        if tree.left is None:
            tree.left = TreeNode(value, None, None)
        return insert(tree.left, value)


def delete(tree: BST, value: Any) -> BST:
    """Remove the value from the tree (if present).

    If the value is not present, this function does nothing.
    """
    try:
        root = (tree.value,)
        print(root[0])
    finally:
        pass

    if tree is None:
        return tree

    elif value < tree.value:
        tree.left = delete(tree.left, value)

    elif value > tree.value:

        tree.right = delete(tree.right, value)
    else:
        if tree.left is None and tree.right is None:  # No children
            if tree.value == root[0]:
                tree.value = None
            return tree
        elif tree.left is not None and tree.right is not None:  # Two children
            replacement = tree.right
            while replacement.left is not None:  # Find smallest "big" value
                replacement = replacement.left
            tree.value = replacement.value  # Set value to smallest "big" value
            tree.right = delete(tree.right, replacement.value)  # Delete value
        else:  # One child
            if tree.left is not None:  # Promote left child
                return tree.left
            else:
                return tree.left
    return tree
```

I'm struggling to delete the root of my BST when one of its left/right components is empty or if both components are empty. Did you guys keep track of your root value throughout your function? I tried implementing a tuple to save keep my root Node, however, my implementation is still running into errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have some code that gives a special meaning to the value `None` in the root node. This is not how it should be done. Your `is_empty` function is right: a tree is empty **only when** the tree reference itself is `None`, not when the root's value happens to be `None`.

So remove this logic (concerning `tree.value is None`) from your `insert` and `delete` functions. And in your main program, initialise your tree as `None`, not as `TreeNode(None)`.

#### Insert

There are some bugs in `insert`:

- In the `value > tree.value` block, when `tree.right` is `None`, your code creates a new node, and **then still** makes a recursive call to insert a node. This is not right. In fact, you should not create a node here at all, but completely rely on the recursive call, which will do that when it gets a `None` as argument.
- In this same block, you should not return what `insert()` returns, which is right subtree. Instead you should assign that return value to `tree.right` and then return `tree`
- In case none of the `if` blocks is entered (which happens when the value is already in the tree), you should still return `tree`.

Here is a correction for `insert`:

```py
def insert(tree: BST, value: Any) -> BST:
    """Insert the value into the tree in the proper location."""
    if tree is None:
        return TreeNode(value, None, None)
    if value > tree.value:
        tree.right = insert(tree.right, value)  # correction
    elif value < tree.value:
        tree.left = insert(tree.left, value)  # correction
    return tree # missing: must always return BST type
```

#### Delete

There are these issues in the `delete` function:

- There is a trivial bug near the end of the function where you do `return tree.left` in both cases. One of those should be `return tree.right`.
- In the case the node is a leaf you should not return `tree`, but `None` as that will serve for the caller to actually detach that node.
- Not a problem, but the case where there are no children does not need a separate treatment. The code that deals with the 1-child case can also deal with the 0-children case.

Here is a correction for `delete`:

```py
def delete(tree: BST, value: Any) -> BST:
    """Remove the value from the tree (if present).

    If the value is not present, this function does nothing.
    """
    if tree is None:
        return tree
    elif value < tree.value:
        tree.left = delete(tree.left, value)
    elif value > tree.value:
        tree.right = delete(tree.right, value)
    elif tree.left and tree.right: # Has two children
        replacement = tree.right
        while replacement.left is not None:  # Find smallest "big" value
            replacement = replacement.left
        tree.value = replacement.value  # Set value to smallest "big" value
        tree.right = delete(tree.right, replacement.value)  # Delete value
    else:  # Zero or one child (same treatment)
        return tree.left or tree.right  # shorter notation to promote a child
    return tree
```

#### Main program

There was no main program included in your code, so I will provide one here. It includes:

- A utility function to display a tree in a 90° rotated way (with root pictured at the left side), using indentation to indicate *depth*.
- Code that populates a tree.

  Note that the tree starts as `None` (empty) and that the return value of `insert` is always assigned back to `tree`.
- Code that deletes some nodes from this tree.

  Note again that the return value of `delete` is always assigned back to `tree`.

```py
def display(tree: BST, tab: str=""):
    if tree:
        display(tree.right, tab + "  ")
        print(tab, tree.value)
        display(tree.left, tab + "  ")
    

tree: BST = None  # This is an empty tree
for value in (4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7):
    tree = insert(tree, value)
print("populated BST:")
display(tree)

for value in (6,9,1,4):
    print("delete", value)
    tree = delete(tree, value)
    display(tree)
```

This demo program will produce this output:

```
populated BST:
     7
   6
     5
 4
     3
   2
     1
delete 6
   7
     5
 4
     3
   2
     1
delete 9
   7
     5
 4
     3
   2
     1
delete 1
   7
     5
 4
     3
   2
delete 4
   7
 5
     3
   2
```